# Promise not waiting for google OAuth

Tags: javascript, api, promise, oauth-2.0, google-api

I am following the Google Quickstart OAuth guide

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs

My function isn't returning a promise. It runs the Oauth request then the callback, but It won't return a then-able promise.

It runs the request and authenticates successfully, only the main function calling it will resolve before the request is complete and gives undefined, and continuously spams requests because it thinks that the previous one is completed.

I can't seem to get the function to wait for the request to finish resolving. What am I doing wrong?

```
const getAuth = (_callback) => fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  console.log("Getting Auth")
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: '.red + err);
    return;
  }
  console.log("Authorizing the client".green)
  // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the YouTube API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), _callback);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function (err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}
```

With this search function:

```
const search = function (args, _cb) {
    console.log("|| Youtube Search ||".yellow)
    console.log("Asking Google For Auth...".red)
    let results = {} // Search Results
    google.getAuth((auth) => { // OAuth2
        google.searchYoutube(auth, args)
        .then((results)=>{
            console.log(results)
            return results
        })
    })
}

/**
 * Search YouTube with query params. Returns a list of youtube objects.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
const searchYoutube = function (auth, args) {

  var service = google.youtube('v3');
  csv = args.toString()
  console.log("Submitting Query to youtube: ".magenta, csv.green)
  return service.search.list({
      auth: auth,
      "part": [
        "snippet"
      ],
      "maxResults": 25,
      "q": csv
    })
    .catch(err => console.log)
}
```

And calling search like this:

```
    async function SearchYoutube(){
        console.log("Asking Youtube for Search")
        const results = Youtube.search('Spongebob')
        console.log("After search")

        console.log("Got Results: ",results)
    }
```

The console output:

```
Asking Youtube for Search
|| Youtube Search ||
Asking Google For Auth...
After search
Got Results:  undefined
Getting Auth
Authorizing the client
Submitting Query to youtube:  Spongebob
{
  <RESPONSE SUCCESS> ...
```

I figured it out. Just had to study Promisifying.

```
//////////
////////////
/// Promisified OAuth
let AuthenticatedSearch = function (args) {
  console.log("Making an authenticated request to youtube... args: ", args)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    getAuth((auth) => {
      searchYoutube(auth, args)
      .then((response,err)=>{
        if(err) reject(err)
        else {
          console.log("Response: ",response)
          resolve(response)}

      })
    })
  })

}

//////////
/////////////
```

Comment: your `const search = function` takes `_cb` which is never used ... and the function doesn't return anything ... therefore the the results in `.then((results)=>{` are only logged to the console, but not accessible outside that `.then`

Comment: you're also creating `async function SearchYoutube` ... why `async` since you never `await`?

Comment: The _cb() doesn't need to be used, I left it in from a previous test. I just removed it and it still doesnt' work.

Comment: The problem is the getAuth method isn't asynchronous. I try awaiting it but the IDE says it just doesn't matter. The method I'm using is from the google quickstart documentation, I just dont understand how to modify it to make it a promise, instead of using a callback.

Comment: actually it is asyncrhonous - and you're using a callback for the asynchronous result - you're doing it right there, but in `search` you're performing `google.searchYoutube(auth, args)` and doing nothing (except console.log) with those results - as I said in the first comment

Comment: actually, it's not. and if you check my edit you'll see why.

Comment: so you think `fs.readFile` is synchronous? it's description includes `Asynchronously reads the entire contents of a file` - so, that means that `authorize(JSON.parse(content), _callback);` is called asynchronously (nothing to do with the `async` keyword by the way, that just has special meaning with promises) once the file is read ... and you still are not doing anything with the results of `google.searchYoutube` other than logging the result to the console - there's no reason to `return results` as that returned value is going nowhere